# how to write text and an image to a Response.OutputStream in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, webforms

I'm drawing an image and outputing it to web page using the following code:

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(350, 350);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image);
// code using g to draw image here
image.Save(Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
```

This works fine. Now I'd like to add a some text to the output (javascript). However, when I do* either the text isn't displayed or image comes out as garbage.

What's the proper way to do it?

(*- I changed the contenttype and used reponse.write. Also tried writing a byte array of text to the outputstream.)

Comment: You can't mix a GIF and JavaScript code in the same response to an HTTP request.

Comment: I figured as much. I was looking to avoid writing the image to disk and using an img tag.

Comment: You don't have to. As @Lou Franco pointed out, you just have to split it into two requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to respond with HTML that has your Javascript and an `<img>` tag that causes another request where you respond with this image.

Probably change the `<img>` that is requesting this image to an `<iframe>` with src set to the request.

Alternatively, it could be a `<script>` tag that you return JavaScript to and have it add an img to the DOM.

Comment: I can reference the image in the img tag like this <img scr="drawImage.aspx"> in another page?

Comment: sure you can do this. see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

you can write a separate file called imageGrab.aspx for your image code and call this one in another file with javascript. It should work fine. For example

```
<img border=0 height=150 src='ImageGrab.aspx?seqid=3'>
```

imageGrab.aspx.cs will looks like

```
public partial class ImageGrab : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] byteData = new byte[0];

            // fetch the value of parameter into the byte array

            string seq_id = Request.QueryString["seqid"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(seq_id))
            {
                seq_id = "214";
            }


            byteData = DBManager.GetBinaryData(seq_id);

            Response.Clear();

            Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            Response.BinaryWrite(byteData);
            Response.End();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Response.Write(exc.Message);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you still want to do this in one request, then http://danielmclaren.net/2008/03/embedding-base64-image-data-into-a-webpage might be the best way to do it.  It involves base64 encoded data right into the `src` attribute of the `img` tag.  i.e.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS..." />
```

Comment: This works well but not supported by all browsers so make sure to test beforehand.

Comment: I thought doing this but I couldn't find a resource on how to do it that way. Thanks!